# SXA Date Range filter date format

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

Sitecore version: 9.3 using SXA

Is there any way, we can change the format of the date selected while using the Date range filter on the search page on the SXA website. we want to see selected dates in mm/dd/yy format (eg 03/24/2021).

Things we have done:

1. After applying the filter, in the style menu, we changed the date display format.
   [image]
2. On the website search page, after selecting the date in date range filter, it is looking like this:
   [image]

However, we want to see the date in 03/08/2021 format instead of March/08/2021 format.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to set the format as mm/dd/yy?

Comment: @CristiVulturar mm/dd/yy is not present in the drop-list to select the date format. But I added in the data source here /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Search/Enums/Date Format. This worked. Thanks

Comment: Great, I have added the details in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to select the date format as `mm/dd/yy`. I think datepicker is using JQuey datepicker, the date format is different from the standard date and time format defined by Microsoft. The Jquery datepicker format is as below:
The format can be combinations of the following:

```
   d - day of month (no leading zero)
   dd - day of month (two digit)
   o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
   oo - day of the year (three digit)
   D - day name short
   DD - day name long
   m - month of year (no leading zero)
   mm - month of year (two digit)
   M - month name short
   MM - month name long
   y - year (two digit)
   yy - year (four digit)
```

If you don't have the date format in the dropdown you can create it under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Enums/Date Formats`